# Is Minor GC also performed on Survivor spaces along with Eden space?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I understand that minor GC is performed in Eden space in Young generation. The objects which survive GC, move to Survivor space (From). Once, (From) is out of space the objects move to Survivor space (To). Is Minor GC also performed on Survivor spaces ?

Comment: Follow the link it has a good explaination about the garbage collection. http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html. 
For your query read the tab labled "The Generational Garbage Collection Process".

Comment: The link is indeed helpful. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Survivor space is part of young generation, and hence a minor gc will be performed on the survivor spaces.  If an object survives a number of minor gc, then it will be moved to the old generation.

for more details: http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-java-garbage-collection/

Comment: I went through the cubrid blog earlier. However the following points got me into confusion - 1. After one GC in the Eden space, the surviving objects are moved to one of the Survivor spaces. 
2. After a GC in the Eden space, the objects are piled up into the Survivor space, where other surviving objects already exist. <br/> It says, once a Survivor space is full, surviving objects are moved to the other Survivor space. Then, the Survivor space that is full will be changed to a state where there is no data at all. </br/>  when minor GC will be performed in Survivor space

Comment: Minor GC will always be performed on eden and in the process, moving the live objects to survivor.  During this Minor GC, if the survivor space (From) gets full, Survivor space (From) will be swapped with the other survivor space (To).

Comment: when we say "swapped"- does it mean that once, (From) is full, a minor GC will run in Eden and (From) and surviving objects in (From) will be swapped with (To) ?

Comment: sorry I was not clear.  Of the 2 survivor space FROM and TO, TO will always be empty.  When FROM survivor space becomes full, a minor GC will check for any dead objects while moving the live objects to TO.  This process of collecting and swapping on Survivor space can happen multiple times, before the surviving objects are moved to Tenured Space.

Answer (score 0):

the following action takes place from the starting of the memory allocation:

let's assume two Survivor space as X,Y to get out of confusion

1. When an application is launched for the first times, the created objects are moved into the Eden space.at this stage X,Y are empty.
2. When Eden space is full, minor GC take place in the Eden space and it sends live objects into the X survivor space. at this stage X is having objects but Y is empty.
3. when next minor GC happen it take place in the Eden as well as X Survivor space and remaining live objects are sent to the Y saviour space. at this stage X is empty but Y is having live objects.

SO every time these steps repeats, you can refer the [link](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) for better understanding, from above explanation it's indeed that minor GC takes place in the survivor space as well.